CSS styling for dynamic video grid only shows fullscreen video
I tried programming a small interactive Website to show some Videos and Pictures in a dynamic grid. So far, the grid for the pictures works (mostly) like I want and shows all pictures in a grid.
However if I try the same thing for my Videos, I only get showed the first Video in giant.
I want to be able to open the Video in fullscreen when I click it, and I thought maybe that had something to do with why I only see one.
I've tried to change up the CSS, and also tried it without the JS, but neither have worked. I don't know if I did something wrong or my thought process is wrong.


function openFullscreenVideo(video) {
  const overlay = document.createElement('div');
  overlay.className = 'fullscreen-overlay';

  const closeButton = document.createElement('button');
  closeButton.className = 'close-button';
  closeButton.innerHTML = 'Schließen';
  closeButton.onclick = function() {
    closeFullscreen(overlay);
  };

  const fullscreenVideo = document.createElement('video');
  fullscreenVideo.src = video.src;
  fullscreenVideo.controls = true;
  fullscreenVideo.autoplay = true;
  fullscreenVideo.muted = true;
  fullscreenVideo.style.maxWidth = '90%';
  fullscreenVideo.style.maxHeight = '90%';

  const fullScreenButton = document.createElement('button');
  fullScreenButton.innerHTML = 'Vollbild';
  fullScreenButton.onclick = function() {
    if (fullscreenVideo.requestFullscreen) {
      fullscreenVideo.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (fullscreenVideo.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      fullscreenVideo.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (fullscreenVideo.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      fullscreenVideo.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (fullscreenVideo.msRequestFullscreen) {
      fullscreenVideo.msRequestFullscreen();
    }
  };

  fullscreenVideo.onended = function() {
    closeFullscreen(overlay);
  };

  overlay.appendChild(closeButton);
  overlay.appendChild(fullscreenVideo);
  overlay.appendChild(fullScreenButton);
  document.body.appendChild(overlay);
}

function closeFullscreen() {
  const fullscreenImage = document.getElementById('fullscreen-image');
  const fullscreenVideo = document.getElementById('fullscreen-video');
  if (fullscreenImage) {
    document.body.removeChild(fullscreenImage);
  }
  if (fullscreenVideo) {
    document.body.removeChild(fullscreenVideo);
  }
  document.body.style.overflow = 'auto';
}
/* Stil für die Videos im Grid */

.video-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(150px, 1fr));
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: calc(100% - 40px);
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.video-grid video {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 8px;
}


/* Stil für das fullscreen Overlay */

.fullscreen-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.fullscreen-overlay video {
  max-width: 90%;
  max-height: 90%;
}
<div class="container">
  <div id="videos" class="content">
    <div class="video-grid">
      <video src="./Videos/video1.mp4" alt="Video 1" onclick="openFullscreenVideo(this)" controls></video>
      <video src="./Videos/video2.mp4" alt="Video 2" onclick="openFullscreenVideo(this)" controls></video>
      <video src="./Videos/video3.mp4" alt="Video 3" onclick="openFullscreenVideo(this)" controls></video>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




"However if I try the same thing for my Videos, I only get showed the first Video in giant." - you mean, before you even clicked anywhere, to trigger fullscreen for one of them? That doesn't appear reproducible for me, with the HTML & CSS you have given so far: https://jsfiddle.net/szthmeLx/

Yeah I think my content class is causing some errors, I did try it now without and then the Video still shows in fullscreen, but now above everything else that should be showing. Heres the link to the whole code, since I have no Idea where the Problem exactly is: https://jsfiddle.net/gvm8f6Ln/4/

I'm confused as to why the videos are positioned absolute all the time (rather than when they are to overlay everything full screen).

In your function closeFullscreen(), you should remove the entire overlay:
function closeFullscreen() {
  document.querySelector('.fullscreen-overlay').remove();
  document.body.style.overflow = 'auto';
}

And when presenting a grid of videos for a user to choose from, don’t use video elements, because (a) they take a long time to load, and (b) when you play the video, you generally want to see it full screen. Instead, present a grid of video thumbnails, which are just images. When the user clicks an image representing a video thumbnail, then create your overlay with a video element inside.
<div class="video-grid">
  <img src="aaa.png" data-videosrc="aaa.mp4" onclick="openFullscreenVideo(this)">
  <img src="bbb.png" data-videosrc="bbb.mp4" onclick="openFullscreenVideo(this)">
  <img src="ccc.png" data-videosrc="ccc.mp4" onclick="openFullscreenVideo(this)">
</div>

Add a custom data attribute to each image element to store the url of the corresponding video. In the example above I have used videosrc. Then in your function openFullscreenVideo(video) you can assign this value to the video element:
fullscreenVideo.src = video.dataset.videosrc;

PS. Because we are now passing an image element containing a video thumbnail into this function, I suggest renaming the parameter to thumb, so our declaration becomes function openFullscreenVideo(thumb).


function openFullscreenVideo(thumb) {
  const overlay = document.createElement('div');
  overlay.className = 'fullscreen-overlay';

  const closeButton = document.createElement('button');
  closeButton.className = 'close-button';
  closeButton.innerHTML = 'close';
  closeButton.onclick = function() {
    closeFullscreen(overlay);
  };

  const fullscreenVideo = document.createElement('video');
  fullscreenVideo.src = thumb.dataset.videosrc;
  fullscreenVideo.controls = true;
  fullscreenVideo.autoplay = true;
  fullscreenVideo.muted = true;
  fullscreenVideo.style.maxWidth = '90%';
  fullscreenVideo.style.maxHeight = '90%';

  fullscreenVideo.onended = function() {
    closeFullscreen(overlay);
  };

  overlay.appendChild(closeButton);
  overlay.appendChild(fullscreenVideo);
  document.body.appendChild(overlay);
}

function closeFullscreen() {
  document.querySelector('.fullscreen-overlay').remove();
  document.body.style.overflow = 'auto';
}
.video-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(150px, 1fr));
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: calc(100% - 40px);
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.video-grid > * {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.fullscreen-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.fullscreen-overlay video {
  max-width: 90%;
  max-height: 90%;
}
<div class="container">
  <div id="videos" class="content">
    <div class="video-grid">
      <img src="https://www.videoplaceholder.com/static/BigBuckBunny-4979b146b7d4a6c16ae8badfe426fb6e.jpg" data-videosrc="https://storage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" onclick="openFullscreenVideo(this)">
      <img src="https://www.videoplaceholder.com/static/ElephantsDream-0ba875c5c7a5731b1bd50922fb3efe93.jpg" data-videosrc="https://storage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4" onclick="openFullscreenVideo(this)">
      <img src="https://www.videoplaceholder.com/static/ForBiggerFun-aad3ba71910909c48fcdd836024fd363.jpg" data-videosrc="https://storage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerFun.mp4" onclick="openFullscreenVideo(this)">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




That worked perfectly, thank you so much!
